# How to create a round border with 2 discrete colors?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to do a label with a circle with two colors, like this:
[image: expected result]

My code is the following:

```
primary1 = "#026C00"
secondary1 = "#2DBCE9"

class TemplatesIconLabel(qt.QLabel):
    """Label with a colored circular border.
    The left half is blue and the right half is green.
    """
    stylesheet = """
    QLabel { 
        border-width: 10px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0.5, x2:1, y2:0.5,
                      stop:0 %s, stop:0.49 %s, stop:0.51 %s, stop:1 %s);
        }
        """ % (secondary1, secondary1, primary1, primary1)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet(self.stylesheet)
        self.setFixedSize(qt.QSize(51, 51))
```

And the result is weird:

[image: actual result]

I experimented with setting regular colors for the left&right border, and using gradient only for `border-top-color` and `border-bottom-color`, but it does not fix my issue completely.

Comment: try a circular gradient

Comment: same weird pattern with radial gradient. Seems like borders have random behaviors when display gradients.

Comment: Try it: `border-color: green blue blue green;`